# Swift - intrinsicContentSize is not called on time

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview, intrinsic-content-size

I have the following structure in my interface builder:

```
MyCustomView
   StackView 
      Label
      TextField
      Label - is hidden
Button
```

When the button is pressed, the logic of the CustomView should make the bottom label appear and so the IntrinsicContentSize be calculated again. Unfortunately the view is presented properly only after the second button click.

Here is the relevant code:

```
public class MyCustomView: UIView {

...

var subtitle: String! {
    didSet {
        subtitleLabel.isHidden = subtitle.isEmpty
        subtitleLabel.text = subtitle
        invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
}

....

override public var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    stackView.layoutIfNeeded()
    return stackView.bounds.size
}

....

}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: How about adding a call to `setNeedsLayout` on the custom view when you change the `isHidden` property of the label.

Comment: Based on your layout description, you shouldn't need `intrinsicContentHeight` at all. A `UIStackView` will automatically adjust its height when you show/hide one of its arranged subviews.

Comment: @DonMag, I need the 'intrinsicContentSize' so that the customView enclosing the stackView will wrap around the automatically adjusting stackView.

Comment: @vacawama Unfortunately it doesn't wonk

Comment: @Luda - still not clear why you're not using constraints... seems like needing additional code to manipulate a view's `intrinsicContentSize` is extra, unnecessary work that would be prone to other problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line that I was missing is `stackView.setNeedsLayout()` when making one of stackView subviews unhidden.

So this is the working `didSet`:

```
var subtitle: String! {
    didSet {
        subtitleLabel.isHidden = subtitle.isEmpty
        subtitleLabel.text = subtitle
        stackView.setNeedsLayout()
        invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
}
```